# simultaneous struct member initialization and definition in c99

Tags: c, c99

I'm trying to create a trie, and I need to have all the booleans equate to false unless otherwise specified. However, this format for simultaneous member initialization and definition is only valid in c++11 apparently... Is there any way to do this in c99?

```
typedef struct
{
    bool booleans[28] = { false };
    struct node *next[27];
}node;
```

Comment: No, there's no way to do specificaly this in C99.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't initialize inside a type declaration.

But the default initialization gives `0` for all members that are not listed explicitly, which is the same thing as `false` in your case.

So declare `node` without the initialization, and then declare variables with something like

```
node X = { 0 };
```